# Is it possible to reintegrate a Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

As anyone who is familiar with Harry Potter knows, a horcrux is made when someone commits murder and stores a piece of their soul in something. Would it be possible for this someone to later recover and reintegrate their soul piece(s), should they want to?

Comment: Personally, I'd McGuyver it with some crazy glue or epoxy, but I don't believe in souls so what do I know :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Supposedly, yes - via full remorse...

From *Deathly Hallows*:

> Ron: "Isn’t there any way of putting yourself back together?"
>   Hermione: "Yes, but it would be excruciatingly painful."
>   Harry: "Why? How do you it?"
>   Hermione: "Remorse. You’ve got to really feel what you’ve done. There’s a footnote. Apparently the pain of it can destroy you. I can’t see Voldemort attempting it somehow, can you?"

To the best of my knowledge, there's no canon example of anyone actually succeeding in this.

Comment: `there's no canon example of anyone actually succeeding in this` Presumably somebody has though, or else how did the author know this?