# Could a certain character be brought back?

Tags: harry-potter

(SPOILER WARNING HP VII)

> If Voldemort is not dead, being between the two worlds on King's Cross, and if he is perhaps not a ghost, then can he be brought back? (The dead cannot come back through the Veil, but he is "not dead".)

Eg. by a *legendary*, powerful wizard, powerful like the Peverell's?

> (Even if of course he is not supported by any horcruxes any more.)

(Please also provide evidence for your answer if possible :)...)

**EDIT**

Please consider that,

> "But you’re dead," said Harry.
> "Oh yes," said Dumbledore matter-of-factly.
> "Then... I’m dead too?"
> "Ah," said Dumbledore, smiling still more broadly. "That is the question, isn’t it? On the whole, dear boy, I think not."
> They looked at each other, the old man still beaming. "Not?" repeated Harry.
> "Not," said Dumbledore.
> So, I think, Voldemort may be not dead, either.

Comment: @Gabe Willard, thanks for the edit :) it's better like this.

Comment: No problem, really. :)

Answer (score 6):

No, it would not be possible to raise Voldemort from the dead, or any other living being at that.

> Though some six centuries have elapsed since Beedle wrote [*Babbity Rabbity and the Cackling Stump*], and while we have devised innumerable ways of maintaining the illusion of
>   our loved ones’ continuing presence, wizards still have not found a way of reuniting body and soul once death has occurred.
>   As the eminent wizarding philosopher Bertrand de Pensées-Profondes writes in his celebrated work *A Study into the Possibility of Reversing the Actual and Metaphysical Effects of Natural Death, with Particular Regard to the Reintegration of Essence and Matter*:
>   “Give it up. It’s never going to happen.”
>   <sub>Albus Dumbledore - *Tales of Beedle the Bard* - pages 78-79 - Collector's Edition - *Babbity Rabbity and the Cackling Stump*</sub>

Could Voldemort's body be reanimated as an Inferi? I think it could be. If one thinks of the body as a receptacle for the soul, and Voldemort's soul is caught in limbo for eternity, turning Voldemort's physical body into an Inferi (Inferi are corpses reanimated by Dark Magic) would be the only way to "bring him back", but Voldemort wouldn't be himself. He'd be a brainless puppet under the control of the dark wizard who created his Inferi form.

Dumbledore also writes:

> As I have already noted in the commentary for “Babbitty Rabbitty and her Cackling Stump”, we remain incapable of raising the dead, and there is every reason to suppose that this will never happen.
>   <sub>Albus Dumbledore - *Tales of Beedle the Bard* - page 97 - Collector's Edition - *The Tale of the Three Brothers*</sub>

Legendary wizard or not, canon does not support resurrection of the dead. In fact, the entire series is about coming to terms with and accepting the finality of death.

**Edited to reflect the question changing.** No, Voldemort cannot come back from being in limbo. He is forced to exist in that state according to J.K. Rowling.

> **Jon:** Since Voldemort was afraid of death, did he choose to be a ghost? If so, where does he haunt, or is this not possible due to his horcruxes?
>   **J.K. Rowling:** No, he is not a ghost. **He is forced to exist in the stunted form we witnessed in King’s Cross**.
>   J.K. Rowling - [Webchat 07.30.08 - THE LEAKY CAULDRON](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript)

I think he's caught between life and death, more towards death, which I think would perhaps be the epitome of Hell for Voldemort.

Comment: I tried to clarify my question, providing information on why do I think that Voldemort is **not dead**.

Comment: @naxa At the point when Harry was in King's Cross with Dumbledore, you're right. Voldemort wasn't dead then. The Voldemort on the platform with Harry was the piece of Voldemort's soul that lived inside Harry. It had just been destroyed by Voldemort's Killing Curse. At that point, Voldemort was still walking around, taunting the surviving Order, and gloating over Harry's defeat. That piece of Voldemort at King's Cross was no more salvageable than *any* destroyed Horcrux.

Comment: Come on! The Dark Lord' is not captured in limbo for ever.  Once all the pieces of his soul die, just give them enough time to heal a bit and he will surely go on.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your clarifications. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess, thank you very much! On the other hand, the term "forced to exist" implies a force, that *may* be changed by a very powerful wizard, and even if he cannot become a ghost, it's unclear whether not-actually-dead people could be raised from that limbo.

Answer (score 1):

I'll reiterate what Gabe said in a comment, based on your clarification.

You seem to be asking whether the soul of Voldemort that Harry sees at King's Cross as a deformed child can be brought back to life since it's now in limbo.

However, that soule piece is NOT Voldemort's main one (the one inside his body) since at the time of King's Cross scene, he was not yet killed by the rebounding Avada Kedavra. What that deformed child is, is the soul fragment that previously resided in Harry's body, and cause Harry to be the "almost-Horcrux".

As such, that fragment was impossible to salvage, since Voldemort would never have gone through what was necessary to reunite the soul fragments, as discussed in HP7 (remorse, quite painful and possibly deadly). See [this SFF answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10600/is-it-possible-to-reintegrate-a-horcrux/10611#10611) for details.

Comment: What is your basis for saying that the deformed child is the soul fragment from Harry's body?  Keep in mind that when Voldemort cast Avada Kedavra, he himself collapsed as well.

Comment: @Kyralessa - why would the "Voldemort's" piece of soul be inside Harry's King's Cross that's "in his head" as per Dumbledore?

Comment: well, for that matter, why would Dumbledore be there?

Comment: Harry wanted him there.

Comment: +1. I was too lazy to post it as a full answer. :P